# Set animation for camera position from beginning to end in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have my current position of the camera, and the final position (focusing on an element). I would like to make an animation of the camera going from the beginning to the end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is create a [unit vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitVector.html) which represents direction from camera to object. Then using this value for changing camera's vector position in time:

```
var speed = 4;
var p = camera.position;
var dt = p.clone();
dt.normalize();
dt.multiplyScalar(speed);
```

And then in render function:

```
function render () {
    if (camera.position.length() > 0) {
        camera.position.sub(dt);
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dc3La82y/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I applied that, the problem is that I try to render in bucle while the camera is approaching the element, but it only shows it when it reached it, nothing shows in the way to the object.

Here is the code:

```
 var cameraPos = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(elementCenter, new THREE.Vector3(distance, distance, distance));
    var cameraLook = new THREE.Vector3(elementCenter.x, elementCenter.y, elementCenter.z);


    //camera.position.set(cameraPos.x, cameraPos.y, cameraPos.z);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(cameraLook.x, cameraLook.y, cameraLook.z));

    var dx = camera.position.x - cameraPos.x;
    var dy = camera.position.y - cameraPos.y;
    var dz = camera.position.z - cameraPos.z;
    var p = new THREE.Vector3(dx, dy, dz);
    var speed = 400;
    var dt = p.clone();
    dt.normalize();
    dt.multiplyScalar(speed);
    var times = p.length() / speed;

    for ( i = 0; i < times; i++ ) {
        camera.position.sub(dt);
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(cameraLook.x, cameraLook.y, cameraLook.z)); //because it is changed when camera moves, I have to give it its value again
        render();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
```